# How do I capture output into a variable and still have it goto the screen too?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, command-substitution

I can do `OUTPUT=$(grunt test)` and that puts the output into `OUTPUT` but it's no longer on the screen. I need to see the output as it comes as well, so I can't just wait and then `echo $OUTPUT`.

How can I capture the output of a program *and* still have it goto the screen at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
exec 9>&1
OUTPUT=$(grunt test | tee /dev/fd/9)
exec 9>&-
```

It copies the current stdout to file descriptor 9, uses `tee` to replicate `grunt`'s output to that file descriptor, then afterwards closes the temporary file descriptor.